# 500 Internal Server Error when crawling a big website

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, web-crawler

I am using following script to get all links from a website. This script works well when I put $depth = 8 or less, But to crawl big site when I want to use $depth = 9999 then it shows following error.

*Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@home.example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

I tried ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);    But still not working, Please someone tell me that how can I crawl more than 10000 pages at a time.

Script is following

```
<?php
class crawler
{
    protected $_url;
    protected $_depth;
    protected $_host;
    protected $_useHttpAuth = false;
    protected $_user;
    protected $_pass;
    protected $_seen = array();
    protected $_filter = array();

    public function __construct($url, $depth = 3)
    {
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_depth = $depth;
        $parse = parse_url($url);
        $this->_host = $parse['host'];
    }

    protected function _processAnchors($content, $url, $depth)
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        @$dom->loadHTML($content);
        $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

        foreach ($anchors as $element) {
            $href = $element->getAttribute('href');
            if (0 !== strpos($href, 'http')) {
                $path = '/' . ltrim($href, '/');
                if (extension_loaded('http')) {
                    $href = http_build_url($url, array('path' => $path));
                } else {
                    $parts = parse_url($url);
                    $href = $parts['scheme'] . '://';
                    if (isset($parts['user']) && isset($parts['pass'])) {
                        $href .= $parts['user'] . ':' . $parts['pass'] . '@';
                    }
                    $href .= $parts['host'];
                    if (isset($parts['port'])) {
                        $href .= ':' . $parts['port'];
                    }
                    $href .= $path;
                }
            }
            // Crawl only link that belongs to the start domain
            $this->crawl_page($href, $depth - 1);
        }
    }

    protected function _getContent($url)
    {
        $handle = curl_init($url);
        if ($this->_useHttpAuth) {
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->_user . ":" . $this->_pass);
        }
        // follows 302 redirect, creates problem wiht authentication
//        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        // return the content
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

        /* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
        $response = curl_exec($handle);
        // response total time
        $time = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);
        /* Check for 404 (file not found). */
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($handle);
        return array($response, $httpCode, $time);
    }

    protected function _printResult($url, $depth, $httpcode, $time)
    {
        ob_end_flush();
        $currentDepth = $this->_depth - $depth;
        $count = count($this->_seen);
        echo "N::$count,CODE::$httpcode,TIME::$time,DEPTH::$currentDepth URL::$url <br>";
        ob_start();
        flush();
    }

    protected function isValid($url, $depth)
    {
        if (strpos($url, $this->_host) === false
            || $depth === 0
            || isset($this->_seen[$url])
        ) {
            return false;
        }
        foreach ($this->_filter as $excludePath) {
            if (strpos($url, $excludePath) !== false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function crawl_page($url, $depth)
    {
        if (!$this->isValid($url, $depth)) {
            return;
        }
        // add to the seen URL
        $this->_seen[$url] = true;
        // get Content and Return Code
        list($content, $httpcode, $time) = $this->_getContent($url);
        // print Result for current Page
        $this->_printResult($url, $depth, $httpcode, $time);
        // process subPages
        $this->_processAnchors($content, $url, $depth);
    }

    public function setHttpAuth($user, $pass)
    {
        $this->_useHttpAuth = true;
        $this->_user = $user;
        $this->_pass = $pass;
    }

    public function addFilterPath($path)
    {
        $this->_filter[] = $path;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->crawl_page($this->_url, $this->_depth);
    }
}






$startURL = 'http://www.example.com/';
$depth = 3;
$username = 'YOURUSER';
$password = 'YOURPASS';
$crawler = new crawler($startURL, $depth);
$crawler->setHttpAuth($username, $password);
// Exclude path with the following structure to be processed 
$crawler->addFilterPath('customer/account/login/referer');
$crawler->run();

?>
```

Comment: What does the logs say? (php log or apache error.log)

Comment: Tell me you aren't trying to run this from a browser?

Comment: @tzunghaor in error_log.txt file  it is showing following error [12-Aug-2015 19:14:15 UTC] PHP Notice:  ob_end_flush(): failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer to delete or flush in /home/***name/public_htmldomain***/index.php on line 85
[12-Aug-2015 19:15:26 UTC] PHP Notice:  ob_end_flush(): failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer to delete or flush in /home/****name/public_html/domain****/index.php on line 85

Comment: @rjdown after coding, I am testing it on browser.

Comment: Those notices tell, that you call ob_end_flush() before ob_start(). I don't see any reason to use those at all: flush() would be enough. However, even the result of flush() might not appear immediately: it depends on the buffering of your server and browser too.

Answer (score 0):

That's difficult to answer. Crawling 10000 pages has a large duration and uses a lot of memory.

But, do (one or more) of the following things:

- Don't print the results of each crawled pages
- Reload the crawlerpage after X crawled pages
- Use a cronjob that crawls each X minutes Y pages